# How to increase the Total Swap used percent of a host programmatically or via a script

Tags: bash, swap, alarm, host, rhel5

The host is RHEL5 and the alarm I want to trigger by running some process or a script is TotalSwapUsedPercent .. is there a quick and easy way?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the TotalSwapUsedPercent:

```
free -t | grep Swap | awk '{print ($3 / $2) * 100 "%"}'
```

You could put that into any monitoring system or cron or whatever you want.